# Loading Rails with mysql to AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying upload my rails app to amazon web services but none of the guides im finding through google are getting me there.  Most are with postgres and im using mysql and others are old and dont seem to work or have you creating a new app and im trying to upload something already in development.  Any help in how to get started with AWS would be helpful

Comment: Did you try AWS Code Deploy: https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy

Comment: I looked through it but couldnt get it up and running correctly...havent dealt with cloud service before so having trouble with the initial setup all the tutorials seem to gloss over things expecting you to know some stuff and terminology

Answer (score 0):

```
how to deploy ON AWS with mysql

Here sudo command doesn't work instead use yum command
1) yum update

(RVM will be installed to  /usr/local/rvm/)
RVM installation so that to work with ruby different versions
2)curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

(To install certificates if the certificates are not installed automatically)
3) gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

(Go where rvm is installed)
4)source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

(to check whether rvm is installed or not)
5) rvm list 

6)rvm install 2.2.1 (This is the ruby version)

7)rvm use 2.2.1 --default

8)Install rubygems 
 rvm rubygems current

9)Install rails
gem install rails

10)Install passenger
gem install passenger 

11)Install nginx
passenger-install-nginx-module
then follow the steps


12)sudo service start nginx

13)Hit on the  ip address to check whether all the things are working correctly

14)Now we will configure  nginx.conf

15)Go to cd /etc/nginx

(Vi is the editor )
16)sudo vi nginx.conf

17) gem install bundler

18) Now installing all gems including mysql by running bundle install
```